# Mysql "is not NULL" is working very slowly

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance, isnull

My query is;

```
 "SELECT firma.id from firma where firma.video IS NOT NULL limit 0,20";
```

It is working after nearly 14 seconds for 576.000 rows at **firma** table. 
 There is only 1 row which is not NULL in video.
 I add index for **video** varchar(1000).

How can i fasten this query ?

Comment: Try adding the word `EXPLAIN` to the front of your query and running it in a SQL editor. It will give you more insight into *why* it is slow, such as if it is building a temp table.

Comment: Try ordering by firma.video ascending(I think) and then you should get null first, if in the list all items are null then get next set of results 19,20 or smth. A bit hackish but try to benchmark this

Comment: "order by firma.video asc" makes it faster thanks a lot.. KA_lin

Answer (score -1):

Do you know about the index content limitation of size? 
By default, the index key prefix length limit is 767 bytes. See [Section 13.1.13, “CREATE INDEX Syntax”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html).